# What's my job name?

Tags: job-search, career-development, title

I am actually finishing my internship at a company. Right now I am trying to find the name of the jobs that I am doing right now !

I graduated with a masters degree in computer graphics. For the last few month I added feature in a rendering engine that already existed. I really love this work of going through code that already exist and try to add new thing to it. So I am more oriented in graphic etc ...

I search in the net but I found a lots of thing, like software developer/engineer, graphic software engineer, graphics programmer/dev, rendering dev ...

But I look like software engineer is more oriented web etc... so I really don't know what is this job name.

Comment: Have you tried asking your boss or looked at your contract?

Comment: Well my tutor didn't know either and name it by default rendering developper

Comment: Software engineer can be almost anything to do with development work. Web is just a subset.

Comment: Surely someone directs your work and manages your tasks, etc.? Why not ask them?

Comment: For me a web developper is more oriented web, like an application developper  is more oriented around mobile (smartphone/tablets). A software developper is either the generic term for all types or developper or specific for those who work on computer software.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your job designation is "Intern (at company X)".

Then, based on the contract / agreement, you can specify the department / unit, like "Intern at company X, Web development", "Intern at company X, Quality Assurance", "Intern at company X, Site reliability" etc.